# fragment - EditText.setText(String) not working when string comes from savedInstanceState but works when hard coded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, screen-orientation, android-textinputlayout

I have a fragment:

`ContactUsFragment.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 *
 */
public class ContactUsFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText et_name, et_phoneno;
    private String name = "", phone = "";
    private boolean instanceSaved = false;

    public ContactUsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            name = savedInstanceState.getString("sv_name");
            phone = savedInstanceState.getString("sv_phone");
            instanceSaved = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("InstanceSaved");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);
        registerETs(view);

        if(instanceSaved) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Instance was saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //--This line works. Gives the correct value of string upon orientation change--
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), phone, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            et_name.setText(name); //--This line does not work--
            et_name.setText("Another String"); //--This  line does not work--
            et_phoneno.setText(phone); //--This line does not work--
        }

        et_name.setText("A String"); //--This line works--

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    public void registerETs(View view) {
        et_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        et_phoneno = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_phoneno);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        savedInstanceState.putString("sv_name", et_name.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putString("sv_phone", et_phoneno.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("InstanceSaved", true);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, the `et_name.setText(name)` inside `if(instanceSaved){...}` is not working. It sets nothing. As if, name is getting `null` value from `if(savedInstanceSaved != null){...}`. But the `Toasts` that I have used inside my various blocks of code is working as expected. It is saving in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){...}`, executing `if(savedInstanceSaved != null){...}`, meaning my `savedInstanceState` is not null and also showing the correct value for `name` string in `if(instanceSaved){...}`. That means my code is working correctly during an `orientation` change. But it is not setting any text in `setText(String)` method.

I also tried using `setText("String")`, and that works. As shown in code. What wrong am I doing and what am I missing? Please help. Thank you.

> NOTE:
>   I am using `EditText`s inside `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`
>
> EDIT:
>   I found that no matter what, `setText(name)` is always taking the initial value of `String name`. Even though `name` in `Toast` shows the new updated value, `setText()` is somehow always using the initial value.
>   Also, I noticed that if I change the orientation thrice, the app crashes.

Comment: .setText(name.toString()) try this way.

Comment: That basically means the value is null

Comment: @MFaisalHyder, that does not work either. And I don't even understand why my app is crashing  every third time I am trying to  rotate the screen.

Comment: @Eenvincible, yes, but the value is not null when I am showing it in a toast. I mean, the string `name` is showing  the value that it saved during orientation change inside the `toast` but the same string cannot set  the value inside `setText(String)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your views have IDs, which they do, then Android will automatically be restoring the view state. This happens after `onCreateView()`. So your code is working, your changes are just lost.

To elaborate, quoting the [official Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)):

> 1. onAttach(Activity) called once the fragment is associated with its activity.
> 2. onCreate(Bundle) called to do initial creation of the fragment.
> 3. onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.
> 4. onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().
> 5. onViewStateRestored(Bundle) tells the fragment that all of the saved state of its view hierarchy has been restored.
> 6. onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user (based on its containing activity being started).
> 7. onResume() makes the fragment begin interacting with the user (based on its containing activity being resumed).

**Update:**

Based on your comment below I'm 99% confident the problem is outside of the code you've displayed. Your problem is that you have two copies of `ContactUsFragment` in memory.

One that has had its state restored, including the `EditText`'s text, and then another one that you must have recreated. Hence you're seeing the toast pop-up (as the old fragment is restored), but you're not seeing the values you place in the `EditText`, because you've replaced the old fragment's view with the new `ContactUsFragment`'s view, which has not been restored.

Comment: My views have IDs, but  they are not getting automatically restored during orientation change. Moreover, my app crashes at every third orientation change with the LogCat error `NullPointerException` at `savedInstanceState.putString("sv_name", et_name.getText().toString());`

Comment: @SajibAcharya I can assure you your `EditText` is having it's old text value restored, it's not negotiable, it's how Android works. The `NullPointerException` is a different issue, please create a new question.

Comment: I am sure Android works that way. But in my case, opposed to that, the the text value is not getting restored. That is why I posted this question. I can put screen shots if you want. About the `NullPointerException`, I shall create a new question, but I need to solve  this problem first. My fragment state is not getting saved on orientation change.

Comment: @SajibAcharya I've updated my answer with the solution to your problem - well, rather the explanation of the cause. It's up to you stop instantiating two fragments.

Comment: Yes, I  was re-creating  the fragment every time during orientation change. I have corrected that and everything is working fine. thank you  so much for your response. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am tried many things but finally, i got the solution it's very simple..before we know how the android main the RestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState basically using view id

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:id="@+id/ids1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/ids2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

assign the id for both views ..now the android maintain the data state on screen orientation changed